# How do I customize the dimensions for plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have added exact numbers to my barplot and now it won't fit the space. How can I fix this?
PROBLEM:

[image]

Code:

```
    ax = df.plot.barh(y='1960', rot=0,title='Five most populous countries and its population',color=['cyan', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'black'])
    for j, v in enumerate(list(df['1960'])):
        ax.text(v, j, " "+str(round(v,2)), color='blue', va='center', fontweight='bold')
    ax.set_xlabel("Population in mln")
    ax.set_ylabel("")
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    fig = ax.get_figure()
    fig.savefig('C:\\Users\\rysza\\Desktop\\python data analysis\\zajecia3\\figure'+str(i)+'.jpeg',bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hack for this is to manually set the limits:

```
...
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_xlim(0, 800)
```

Output:

[image]